# Relation between weight of the aircraft and mach number

Tags: aerodynamics, airspeed, propulsion, cruise

Is there any formula that relates weight of the aircraft with mach number?

Comment: Without any other parameters? There are a lot of factors that go into speed. This is kind of like asking if there is any relation between a cars weight and how fast it can go...

Comment: What makes you think there might be a relation between the two?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Weight (which is a result of mass and gravity) is not related to mach number (which depends on velocity and the local speed of sound). You are comparing apples and oranges.